# How to get Webpath using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to show the webpath of all categories. For example I have the following structure

Cat1

- catFile1.1
- catFile1.2
- catFile1.3

Cat2

- CatFile2.1
- CatFile2.2

Cat3

- Cat3

Cat4

When I click Category 1 and then Category 2 it should show me the Path on top  like
Cat1 -> Cat2 . Path should tell where I am standing in which category. 
How can get this behaviour using javascript or is there another way to do that ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways to implement a breadcrumb. It really depends on the structure of your site.

Comment: If the categories are different pages, you would need cookies to save the breadcrumbs. Better to store the paths in a session